# Moving a php project to codeigniter or updating the existing framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, framework-migration

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a php project going forward. It was built a few years ago on a custom framework - the framework wasnt strict MVC...it simply had controllers and views, and libraries.

I've since added in additional functionality and it's starting to feel very much like a complete mess, with old code and new code mixed up, and no decent database management.

I'm struggling to decide what my best option is. On the one hand, I could keep patching the existing codebase in the hope that I can make it somewhat more usable and futureproof, or move to codeigniter (note: I say codeigniter as I've got a fair amount of experience with it).

The Codeigniter option would obviously mean I'd have to go through everything, and there will no doubt be a fair amount of recoding, however in the long term it may be worth it.

There was another option I was considering, and that was the Laravel framework. I have no direct experience with it, however I hear that Laravel 4 (not released yet) is supposed to be excellent.

So, putting those three options on the table, which would you pick and why? I'm looking for a compelling reason to choose one over the other, as quite frankly I dont have a clue which route I'm best taking at the moment!

Comment: Completely depends on what the mess you've got is supposed to do and how it is expected to change? Does it earn money directly, e.g. a shop or other paid service? Does it support earning money, e.g. website explaining stuff? Does it exist pro bono? Who would pay for changing to a solution of your choice? If nothing else is coming up, go for the Codeigniter solution, because you know this best - probably it's the least effort to get stuff done there.

Comment: It's a web-based membership system that we license out to our clients. They then use it for their members. Cost wise, it would be out of our own pocket, but I see it as a worthwhile investment if it means future development will be faster and more efficient. I could be wrong, but it just seemed logical to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### <sub>Short answer: *neither*.</sub>

### Now a bit longer version..

I get the impression, that you are confused about, which problems frameworks aim to solve. When you use a framework, what you gain is shorter development for simple applications. What you always loose is performance and, usually, maintainability.

Frameworks are made to provide you with tools for solving simple problems. Which means that there is a lot of thing's, that you do not need. And there is also problems, that frameworks do not solve or even actively hinder your efforts in making a solution.

### What you should do instead..

Refactor your code.

If you have been working on the project for long time, you will have a lot of lessons, that you learned from this experience. Utilize them by improving the existing codebase.

- if there are flaws in your architecture: **restructure broken parts**
- if you are not sure, whether something works: **add unittests**
- if something seems to be slow: **profile you code and optimize**
- if you do not know what something does: **find out and add comments**

This way you will enhance both you project and your skills.

> <sub>**P.S**
>
>   Even if you were starting new project, I would recommend to avoid both frameworks. They both are filled with bad practices and worse code: global state everywhere, procedural programming, misinterpretation of MVC, disregard for OOP principles and laws.</sub>

Comment: It is common courtesy to explain why you downvoted an answer.

Comment: not sure who's doing the downvoting - not me (the op) though. Thanks for your detailed post :)

Comment: +1 for the PS, more people should realize this

Comment: Whilst I do agree with the P.S comment, surely this would mean long-term pain. The only obvious gain I'm seeing (and please correct me if I'm wrong) is that you get a better respect for coding practices. Whilst I'm always all for improving my understanding of principles, surely doubling the development time isn't the best way of doing this?

Comment: But you said you already have a finished project. Slapping on a framework on existing code-base would yield no benefits. It would not make code magically better or faster.

Comment: In my experience at least, using a (caveats: well structured, popular) framework has always led to an increase in maintainability, not a decrease.

Comment: So you are saying that slapping on a framework, in your experience, somehow magically makes the code better. Either you experience is extremely limited, or your code is extremely bad. Especially if something as horrible as CodeIgniter would improve your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually had experience with this, as I recently moved an older site from what was essentially a modular Model-View setup to CodeIgniter (with the MX modular extension).  It didn't take too long and easily the longest part of it was converting the models over to CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord paradigm.

It sounds like you don't even have any model conversion to do, so I'd say converting to CodeIgniter shouldn't be too much of a challenge, especially given your experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definite right or answer - there will have to be an investment made in time either now or spread out in the future.

Personally, I'd bite the bullet and go with migrating to CI.  If you're fighting your code more than fixing it then the effort you put in the short term will be worth it in the long run.

Most of the time, it doesn't take much time to get an existing PHP application into CodeIgniter - you'll just have to spend more time re-organizing your code afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to Laravel and its already compatible to php v5.3+ with a great community. I did use CI for many projects but getting along with Laravel was one of my best decision. L3 is stable and doing perfectly well and L4 is going to redefine the use of php maximizing efficiency.

If you have your old system well structured in form of OOP standards then u can invest a little bit of time to migrate the usable potions to Laravel and also combine super features of Laravel to save lots of your time. For example Laravel uses well structured ORM called Eloquent and can snap in all your data models in just few minutes. If you also take a look at the active community you will be a happy man to get quick support.

Comment: ORM instances are **not** models. Model is a layer in MVC. What you call "well structured" is an all-static active record implementation.

Comment: Ofcause and in Model layer we can have data models to interact with controllers and views. I am sure you will know what its like to do a good TDD based development and having Factories and IoC to work along and using other patterns like Facade etc. Which is kind of a mixed design structure when we talk about Laravel. Its all up to the developer to workout with best practices and Laravel fits to any of it. L4 definitely will get more improvements too.

Comment: Hi Raf - glad to have someone here who's had Laravel experience. Is L4 ready for use yet? My only worry is that I'd code it all in L3 and have a hell of a time moving to L4.

Comment: @RickM I am using L3 and have no fear to migrate to L4 when it gets released. L4 is mainly going to be full of Composer packaging so if you follow the standards you will not have a hard time and if even if you have a problem i am sure the active community of Laravel will give you a hand.